# $2^2 \cdot U_6(2)$ and $2^2.2^{1+20}U_6(2)$ in $\mathbb{M}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, sporadic-groups

In the first diagram of [this paper](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Ebaumeist/wop2017/slides/Fischer80.pdf), there are conjugacy classes of subgroups of the Monster group which are labeled $2^2 \cdot U_6(2)$ and $2^2.2^{1+20}U_6(2)$, respectively. Can subgroups in the first of these embed into those in the second?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I computed $H^2(U_6(2),2^{20})$, which is zero, so the quotient $2^{20}U_6(2)$ of the second subgroup must be split, which makes it very plausible that there is such an embedding. (There is however a non-split extension $2^{22} \cdot {\rm Co}_2$, so it seems likely that that quotient  of $2.2^{1+22}{\rm Co}_2$ is non-splt.)

Comment: @DanielSebald: Is your question about (a) the existence of an injection from one to the other, or (b) the existence of representatives $H_1$ and $H_2$ of your two conjugacy classes of subgroups of $M$ such that $H_1\le H_2$?

Comment: @RichardLyons I meant (b). I also edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Both subgroups sit inside $2^2{\cdot}({^2E_6(2)})$, and I see now from the ATLAS that the extension $2^{1+20}.U_6(2)$ (as maximal subgroup of $^2E_6(2)$) is split, so interpretation (b) looks very plausible.

Comment: According to the diagram, the answer must be 'yes.' Let $H$ and $K$ be the diagram subgroups labelled $2^2U_6(2)$ and $K=2^2.{^2}E_6(2)$. Since $H\le 2Fi_{22}\le K$, $Z(H)\not\le Z(K)$ and so $H\le C_K(u)$ for some involution $u\in Z(H)-Z(K)$. Since $C_K(u)$ involves $U_6(2)$, $C_K(u)$ must be conjugate to the $2^2.2^{1+20}U_6(2)$ subgroup in the diagram (thanks to the Borel-Tits theorem).